# É possivel converter pdf para png sem usar o imagick?

Tags: php

Eu estou gerando um documento em pdf e queria converte ele para png, mas a hospedagem do cliente não aceita extensões do php como o imagick, procurei bastante na net mas só acho opções que usa o imagick, alguém tem alguma ideia se é possível fazer sem e como?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algumas hospedagens podem possuir o ImageMagick instalado, mesmo sem ter a extensão do PHP. Nestes casos, pode-se invocar o programa diretamente do sistema através do "exec()" do PHP:

```
<?php
$location   = "/usr/local/bin/convert"; // Localização do "convert" do imagick
$name       = "original.pdf"; 
$nameto     = "covertido.png";
$convert    = $location . " " . $name . " ".$nameto; // Comando
exec ($convert); // Executa o comando

echo "PDF convertido para PNG!!";
```